# Proxy Auto Config (PAC) dnsResolve() function return values

Tags: proxy, pac

Good Morning!

I have a rather simple question.  Does anyone have a function reference for the dnsResolve() function in Proxy Auto Configuration scripts?  Or for that matter, a function reference for all the PAC functions?  I'm looking for specifics, such as return types, error values, etc. Not examples of how to use it.

i.e. dnsResolve() returns string IP address on success or bool false on failure.

This is the closest I've found:

```
dnsResolve(host)
hosthostname to resolve
Resolves the given DNS hostname into an IP address, and returns it in the dot separated format as a string.

Example:
dnsResolve("home.netscape.com")returns the string "198.95.249.79".
```

But it doesn't list what is returned if it can't resolve it (does it return false? return original argument?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has a nice set of docs for the IPv6 Aware APIs.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg308477(v=vs.85).aspx

The IPv4 APIs mostly operate the same way other then they do not support IPv6 addresses.  Here is a [list of changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg308474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is a link to the old Netscape specification of the [PAC functions](http://web.archive.org/web/20060424005037/wp.netscape.com/eng/mozilla/2.0/relnotes/demo/proxy-live.html).

In any case I am pretty sure that if `dnsResolve()` doesn't get a useful value, then it returns an empty string.

Comment: Ah, the Microsoft link works quite well, thanks!

I was already using the Netscape specification and it only listed the return value on success.